# How to get number of column in an Array array?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, ocaml

If I have a two-dimensional array, how can I get the number of columns ?

I can get number of lines with `Array.length(o)` where o is an 5*10 matrix, which returns 5.

But how to do with columns?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming there is at least one "line", and that the column arrays are of equal length, just take the length of the first "column" array:

```ml
Array.length m.(0)
```

If there are no lines however, this will raise an exception.

Comment: And if the lines are not equal the result will be meaningless. But an array of arrays of different length is possible. The type system doesn't ensure equal lengths. If you want something safe then create your own type `matrix` that only allows well formed (and non empty) arrays of arrays.